# Safari Embedded QR Code scanner in iOS 11?

Tags: mobile-safari, qr-code, ios11

Now that Apple has added QR Code scanning to their photo app, and iOS Chrome is able to scan codes too, I'm wondering if there is a way to embed a QR Code Scanner in a Web App (and have it work in Safari).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using **WebRTC** i'm not sure if you can use the apple embedded Qr reader

try this link https://github.com/centogram/instascan

Answer (score 0):

I came across this PWA QR Code scanner project that seems to work well in both Android and iOS.

It's open source, and works offline:

https://github.com/code-kotis/qr-code-scanner